# Entity Framework Invalid Column Name 'Model_Key'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm relatively new to Entity Framework so I may be missing something obvious here, but I'm attempting to create a new application using some existing database architecture. I'm unsure how much information you'll need here, so I'll put as much as I can.

I have three Models and I'm trying to set them up so that they are all related to each other.

**LocatorTier**

```
[Table("locator_tag_definitions")]
public class LocatorTier
{
    public enum TierClassification
    {
        Tier1 = 16,
        Tier2 = 17,
        Tier3 = 18
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("TagID")]
    public int LocatorTagID { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string SectionName { get; set; }

    [Column("ClassificationTagID")]
    public TierClassification tierClassification { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public int LocatorID { get; set; }
    public List<LocatorAttribute> LocatorAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

**LocatorAttribute**

```
[Table("locator_tags_attributes")]
public class LocatorAttribute
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int LocatorAttributeID { get; set; }
    public int LocatorID { get; set; }

    [Column("TagID")]
    public int LocatorTagID { get; set; }
    public int CatalogueID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocatorAttributeDefinitions")]
    public int AttributeDefID { get; set; }
    public List<LocatorAttributeValue> LocatorAttributeValues { get; set; }
}
```

**LocatorAttributeValue**

```
[Table("assets_attribute_values")]
public class LocatorAttributeValue
{
    [Key]
    public int ValueID { get; set; }
    public int AttributeDefID { get; set; }
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public string ShortValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling this in my controller with the following code:

```
LocatorTier locatorTier = StoreDB.LocatorTier.Include(lt => lt.LocatorAttributes.Select(lta => lta.LocatorAttributeValues)).Single(i => i.LocatorID == 940 && i.tierClassification == LocatorTier.TierClassification.Tier1);
```

Everything works as expected if I don't try to bring in **LocatorAttributeValue**, but when I do I'm presented with the following error:

> Invalid column name 'LocatorAttribute_LocatorAttributeID'.

I believe this is because my table "assets_attribute_values" doesn't have a column called "LocatorAttributeID". However I expect this and have tried to set the relationship up so that the two tables are linked via the "AttributeDefID" column as such;

[image: The tables]

What am I doing wrong here and is there any way I can link these up without modifying the database tables?

Comment: When I have seen this message before, it is usually because I missed a EntityTypeConfiguration file from the modelBuilder.Configuations

Answer (score 0):

After trying random changes I've found the cause of the problem.

The issue was with how I was defining my ForeignKey. By changing

```
[ForeignKey("LocatorAttributeDefinitions")]
public int AttributeDefID { get; set; }
public List<LocatorAttributeValue> LocatorAttributeValues { get; set; }
```

to

```
public int AttributeDefID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AttributeDefID")]
public List<LocatorAttributeValue> LocatorAttributeValues { get; set; }
```

The code worked correctly.

I guess for anyone who has had the error **Invalid column name 'Model_Column'**, they should check if they've included a ForeignKey tag. The Foreign key should be assigned to the list or collection and must be set to a value shared by both tables.

I'm unsure here if my ForeignKey relates to **AttributeDefID** in my **LocatorAttribute** model, or my **LocatorAttributeValue** model. But either way this works.. perhaps somebody more experienced could share some more concise and informed information...